# Would all questions listed in the bitmessage proposal be on-topic on IT Security?

Tags: support, scope

Over at Area51, the [Bitmessage proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58739/bitmessage) is receiving close votes for being a duplicate of IT Security.  Are all example questions on-topic here?  Currently, those are:

- *What are some alternative clients to the Pybitmessage client?*
- *How do I properly back-up the keys.dat file?*
- *Why does Bitmessage use XMLRPC instead of something newer like JSON/REST?*
- *Can I create a vanity BM address?*
- *How does Bitmessage prevent address collision?*

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a look at these sample questions:

- **What are some alternative clients to the Pybitmessage client?**
  No, this would not be on topic here (although it's already been asked) - but I don't think this should be ontopic on *any* SE site, this specifically asks for product recommendations ("shopping list" questions) which have been deemed to not be a good fit for StackExchange in general (and explicitly forbidden on most sites).
- **How do I properly back-up the keys.dat file?**
  This sounds more like a [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) question, rather than a Sec.SE question. I am not sure I would close this question, though, it does depend on the content - for example, perhaps the question is asking for a backup *process*, and how to go about safeguarding the backups, rather than a simple "how-to".
- **Why does Bitmessage use XMLRPC instead of something newer like JSON/REST?**
  I don't see how this is an answerable question on *any* site (and about any product), unless the original developer/designer/architect happen to stop by to answer. In fact, why not go ask them?
- **Can I create a vanity BM address?**
  Off topic. Definitely not a security question.
- **How does Bitmessage prevent address collision?**
  Okay! Now where getting somewhere. Assuming Bitmessage has an open protocol (I am not familiar), this could be something we might be able to sink our teeth into - unless it happens to more a Crypto.SE type question....

**To sum up, I would say that so far it does *not* look like a good fit to merge into Sec.SE.**
To be clear, I am not saying anything about it's suitability as a site, I just don't think its a duplicate of Sec.SE, as it stands now.